# State-space transformation of differential equation with a single input that includes delay and non-delay

Tags: control-theory, delay-differential-equations

I have a second-order vector differential equation

$$\mathbf{M}\ddot{\mathbf{x}}(t)+\mathbf{C}\dot{\mathbf{x}}(t)+\mathbf{K}\mathbf{x}(t)=\mathbf{P}\mathbf{u}(t)$$

in which the input vector is of the form

$$\mathbf{u}(t)=[r(t)~~r(t-\tau)]^T$$
where $r(t)$ is scalar and $\tau$ is a known delay.

Such systems appear in e.g. vehicle dynamics, where the front wheelset is excited by $r(t)$ and the rear wheelset is excited by the same input, after some delay that depends on the velocity of the vehicle and the wheelbase.

Is it at all possible to bring the above system to state-space, where the input is only $r(t)$? That is,

$$\dot{\mathbf{\xi}}(t)=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{\xi}(t)+\mathbf{B}r(t)\\
\mathbf{y}(t)=\mathbf{C}\mathbf{\xi}(t)+\mathbf{D}r(t)$$

As a possible solution may provide "strange" attributes to the matrices $\mathbf{B}$ and $\mathbf{D}$, could such a system be accordingly discretized using, say, zero-order hold?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With the help of Laplace transform and assuming null initial conditions, we have

$$
\left(s^2M+sC+K\right)\hat x(s)=P\hat u(s)
$$

with $\hat u(s) = (1,e^{\tau s})\hat r(s)$

Comment: Laplace/Fourier transform is a tool, as mentioned by Cesareo. Alternatively, since $\mathbf{u}(t)$ is just a "parameter" (and not the wanted variable), you can simply set $\tilde{r}(t) := r(t-\tau)$.

Comment: Check out this paper https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1103023

Comment: @KBS Thanks! I am indeed exploring the Artstein transformation. In fact, i am trying to confirm that the solution of the system $$\mathbf{\dot{\xi}}(t)=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{\xi}(t)+\mathbf{B}_0\mathbf{u}(t)+\mathbf{B}_1\mathbf{u}(t-\tau)$$ is equivalent to the solution of the system $$\mathbf{\dot{\zeta}}(t)=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{\zeta}(t)+\Big(\mathbf{B}_0+e^{\mathbf{A}\tau}\mathbf{B}_1\Big)\mathbf{u}(t)$$

Comment: @user2445383 That's correct and this is one of the examples given in the paper I mentioned.

Comment: There is a minus term missing at the exponential, though.

Comment: @Abezhiko But then you lose the coupling of the two inputs. By redefining the delayed input as a new input you get a different system because in the original system the second input is constrained to be a delayed version of the first input.

Answer (score 3):

One way to discretize the system
$$
\dot{x}(t)=Ax(t)+B_0u(t)+B_1u(t-h)
$$

using a zero-order hold is to consider that the delay is a multiple of the sampling period. Let $T$ be the sampling period and $N$ be an integer such that $h=NT$.

Then, a discretized version of the system is simply given by

$$\begin{bmatrix}
x_{k+1}\\
\hline
u_{k}\\
u_{k-1}\\
u_{k-2}\\
\vdots\\
u_{k-N+1}
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
e^{AT} & | & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & \Psi(T)B_1\\
\hline
0 & | & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0& 0\\
0 & | & I & 0 & \ldots & 0& 0\\
0 & | & 0 & I & \ldots & 0& 0\\
\vdots & | & \vdots & & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & | & 0 & 0 & \ldots & I & 0
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x_{k}\\
\hline
u_{k-1}\\
u_{k-2}\\
u_{k-3}\\
\vdots\\
u_{k-N}
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
\Psi(T)B_0\\
\hline
I\\
0\\
0\\
\vdots\\
0
\end{bmatrix}u_k
$$
where $\Psi(T)=\int_0^Te^{As}ds$.

Let me know if this is of any help and I will update the answer accordingly.